# Reading errors into VBA from excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to determine if a specific cell contains an error value. I've been trying to use the IsError function but am not sure what syntax to use.

If cell D4 contains a #N/A here's my current code:

```
Dim curCol As String
Dim tmp As Boolean
curCol = "$D$"
tmp = WorksheetFunction.IsError(TListSheet.Cells(curCol & "4").Values)
```

The last line above ends function execution causing a #VALUE in the cell it was called from.
TListSheet is the code name of the sheet I'm using and theres another function that returns curCol as $D$ so I can't just hardcode that value into the IsError function

Comment: Try it without the `WorksheetFunction.`

Comment: Also, I think you need to take the 's' off of 'Values'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to:

1. create an error
2. test for the error

.

```
Sub MakeErrorTestError()
    Range("B9").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(0,0,0)"
    MsgBox Range("B9").Text
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a way to test for any errors and an error in a specific cell:

```
Sub MakeErrorTestError()
    Dim rError As Range
    Range("B9").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(0,0,0)"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rError = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    If rError Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No errors"
    If Intersect(Range("B9"), rError) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No error in B9"
    Else
        MsgBox "error in B9"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not trying to have the program tell me that the cell contains an error, I need a way for it to internally say that there's an error so I can create an If statement to deal with it

Comment: I discovered that my problem was that the cell with the error was returning a custom error message from someone else's custom function not an actual error object. Here's the code I ended up using...

If TListSheet.Cells(4, colNum).Value <> "#N/A N/A" Then

Thanks for trying Gary's Student, I appreciate the effort. Sorry that I was asking the wrong question